# Erro no botão de compra Opencart

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, syntax-error, opencart

Ao clicar no botão comprar ele nao faz nada, pelo console aparece o seguinte erro

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #product
>   input[type='text'], #product input[type='hidden'], #product
>   input[type='radio']:SELECTED=TRUE, #product
>   input[type='checkbox']:checked, #product select, #product textarea

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:SELECTED=TRUE, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-cart').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#button-cart').button('reset');
    },
```

site:www.personaleplantas.com.br

Answer (score 0):

Erro esta aqui:

```
 data:$('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:SELECTED=TRUE, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
```

Isso não é um array, não é valor, não é nada, você precisa extrair os valores desses campos antes, por exemplo:

```
data:{
    $('#product input[type=\'text\']').val(),
    $('#product input[type=\'hidden\']').val(),
    $('#product input[type=\'radio\']:selected').val(),
    $('#product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked').val(),
    $('#product select option:selected').val(),
    $('#product textarea').val()
},
```